# C# LINQ Grouping Question

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object which is structured as below

```
public MyObject{
    int SomeNumber {get;set;}
    Object SomeObject {get;set;}
    Object SomeOtherObject {get;set;}
}
```

Now SomeNumber is not unique, If I have an IEnumerable How can I pull out an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` that all have the same SomeNumber Value?

I assume I need to use GroupBy to do this? But cant seem to get it right.

Edit: I dont know what SomeNumber is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myObjects = new List<MyObject>(); // fill        

var groups = from item in myObjects group item by item.SomeNumber;
// alternatively:
// var groups = myObjects.GroupBy(item => item.SomeNumber)

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    var someNumber = g.Key;
    var members = g.ToList();
}
```

should do.

Comment: You should be able to remove `into g select g`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Cool, adjusted that

Answer (score 5):

No need for `GroupBy` unless you want to make groups of them.

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> myEnumerable ...
myEnumerable.Where(o => o.SomeNumber == value);
```

Comment: Good answer. Though, as soon as you want the items for multiple `SomeNumber`s you are better of grouping them. Especially, since you might not know, in which `SomeNumber` you are interested in.

Comment: I dont know what the value is. That might not have been clear in my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> source = something;
var grouped = source.GroupBy(s => s.SomeNumber);
```